# Is it OK to send an HTTP response with file attachment without specifying the Content-Length?

Tags: http, uri, attachment, content-length

Meaning will it work fine? I have a situation where I am attaching files via HTTP attachment by attaching the URI of the file and it is on a different server so I don't have access to the length of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work fine. The client will just read to EOF. The client only won't be able to calculate/estimate the progress of download.

Answer (score 1):

It may work fine but the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) states that applications SHOULD send the length if it's possible to determine:

> Applications SHOULD use this field to
>   indicate the transfer-length of the
>   message-body, unless this is
>   prohibited by the rules in section
>   4.4.
>
> Any Content-Length greater than or
>   equal to zero is a valid value.
>   [Section 4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) describes how to determine
>   the length of a message-body if a
>   Content-Length is not given.
>
> Note that the meaning of this field is
>   significantly different from the
>   corresponding definition in MIME,
>   where it is an optional field used
>   within the "message/external-body"
>   content-type. In HTTP, it SHOULD be
>   sent whenever the message's length can
>   be determined prior to being
>   transferred, unless this is prohibited
>   by the rules in [section 4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).